# Can I create a time series with a reverse-log axis scale, so more recent dates are wider apart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a few recent applications I have plotted some time series where the more recent values are of more interest, but the historical values are good for context.  Here's an example, a [toy tracker for progress](https://github.com/felixvuo/tex-words-worm) on a written project:

[image: plot of progress on a dissertation]

Ideally I would like the more recent dates to be shown more spread out on the x-axis, but still labelled correctly as dates.  This would look a bit like a logarithmic scale in reverse.  I think this idea might be quite useful for timelines in contexts where progress accelerates over time, e.g. computation power.

I've looked at this [matplotlib "timeline" example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html) for inspiration, but can't quite see how to achieve the spacing and labelling I want.

Here is a minimal example to work with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO

data = '''when,words
2019-11-11,537
2019-12-19,530
2020-03-16,876
2020-08-10,1488
2021-02-05,2222
2022-01-21,2839
2022-03-02,3050
2022-03-04,3296
2022-03-15,3370
2022-03-23,3575
2022-04-25,2711
2022-06-06,3014
2022-06-28,3130
'''

prog = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['when'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
sns.lineplot(ax=ax,data=prog,x="when",y="words",markers=True,marker="o")
ax.set(ylim=(0,1.1*prog.words.max()),title="Dissertation Progress")
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()
```

Which produces:
[image]

Comment: it might help to provide a minimal reproducible example here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something along these lines, i.e. converting your dates to number of days and then applying `np.log10()` on them:

```
prog.loc[:,'days'] = -np.log10(abs((prog.when - prog.iloc[-1].when).dt.days - 100))
g = sns.lineplot(x="days",y="words",data=prog,markers=True,marker="o")
_ = g.set_xticks(prog.days.to_list(), prog.when.dt.date.to_list(), rotation=90)
```

This yields this plot:

[image]

You can then handle overlapping labels by manually adjusting the xticklabels.